# Intercept "installtionUpdate" event and provide custom message Microsoft chat bot

Tags: typescript, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a activity handler that is intercepting events and handling them following this [template](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/tree/master/templates/typescript/samples/sample-assistant). We have a bot set to auto install in the Teams tenant and it is receiving the instalationUpdate events and responding back with a greeting. I would like to intercept this event and provide a different response other than the standard greeting that the bot uses. Is there a handler available for this install event? This bot is built in typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go please follow this for customization of your greeting : [Edit your greeting](https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/virtual-assistant/tutorials/customize-assistant/typescript/2-edit-your-greeting/)

The handler which is responsible for sending greeting is [membersAdded](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/55f9edd952aebd5205d34193bcd9180e454b3f2d/templates/typescript/samples/sample-assistant/src/bots/defaultActivityHandler.ts#L64)

UPDATE:

As of now there is no method that gets invoked when user updates an app. However in TeamsActivityHandler we have method that gets invoked when User add or remove an app->  [*onInstallationUpdate(BotHandler)*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder/teamsactivityhandler?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#onInstallationUpdate_BotHandler_).

Refer [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder/teamsactivityhandler?view=botbuilder-ts-latest) to see all method inside TeamsActivityHandler.

Comment: Thank you Hanaid, we have already done those steps you listed. This is just for the event that comes in when the bot is auto installed in the Teams tenant. Here is a scenario that we are trying to handle
publish the app manifest to the teams tenant with permissions to install and update for all users
Publish a update to the app manifest
ALL users in the tenant will receive the standard greeting that is set following the documents you listed
We would like to provide a different greeting just for the update event that comes in from the above steps

Comment: As I understand you are trying to send some different greeting in case you UPDATE the app. As of now we do not have any particular event handler in ActivityHandler to manage a updateEvent.

Comment: Thank you Hunaid. I was hoping there was something in the Teams activity handler, but for now we will not be able to handle this. If you list the above comment as a answer I will mark this as answered.

Comment: @Tom, I have updated the same answer. Provided few important link that you should look.